# Coredata crash when I dismiss a view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I'm building a view that searches through an entity in core data. I populate an array with the result of a search from core data. The code works fine but when I dismiss the view, I get the following error and my app crashes.
My system is XCode 12 Macos catalina
This is the error message I get,
Exception   NSException *   "+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Proveedor'" 0x0000600001be47e0

Code:

```
extension Proveedor {
    
    static func getProveedoresWith(string:String?, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> [Proveedor]? {
        guard let partialString = string else { return nil }
        print(partialString)
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Proveedor>(entityName: "Proveedor")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "nombreFantasia CONTAINS %@", partialString)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombreFantasia", ascending: false)]
        let result = try? context.fetch(request)
        print(result)
        return result
    }
}


struct FaenaManagerSeleccionarProveedorView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @Binding var isShowing:Bool
    @State var aBuscar = ""
    
    var proveedores:[Proveedor]? {
        Proveedor.getProveedoresWith(string: aBuscar, context: context)
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            TextField("value", text: $aBuscar)
                .padding()
                .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .light, design: .monospaced))
            List {
                ForEach(proveedores ?? [], id:\.id) { proveedor in
                    Text(proveedor.nombreFantasia!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could give me a hint please.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the problem was that I was using a background context.

Instead of using a view context.